# RAM manufacturer different from brand name

Tags: laptop, memory, manufacturing

Is it a common thing to have the RAM manufacturer name different from the brand name? I recently installed a TeamGroup Elite RAM and when I checked its infos I get this:
`Manufacturer: 04EF`

Does this mean it is not a genuine product?

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't have a list of codes; but 'TeamGroup' are not a manufacturer. I don't even think they're an assembler, they're just a 'pin a badge on it & flog it out the door' reseller. Here's the list of assemblers & manufacturers - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_hardware_manufacturers#Random-access_memory_(RAM)_modules